# simple attr_accesible in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple rails application were book belongs_to user and user has_many book. In the book model I have a filed for user which is the user_id field and I use devise for my current_user method. Now I want the current_user to add a new bood and I keep getting the error cannot mass-assign protected attributes : item, user. I have no idea were the item is coming from and do I have to include user into the list of attr_assible items. The problem is that I don't want the user attribute in the book to be massisined so people don't just try to hack and change the owner of the book. I am using rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the book model:

```
attr_accessible :user_id
```

Or try this:

```
@book = Book.new
@book.user_id = current_user.id
@book.save
```

Also see:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This is just a workaround. If the book has 10+ attributes, this can become unmaintainable.

Comment: @alfonso Yes. There are many ways to skin this cat. Added the attr_accessible to my response.

Comment: Apart from that is it not possible for hackers to just mass-assign the user_id field

Comment: @UchennaOkafor That can be solved by configuring the security properly: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures

Comment: @UchennaOkafor Exactly why you chose between the two approaches. Usually, I have found this question coming from not understanding the source of the error(`cannot mass-assign protected attributes`) and ways to get past that error, rather than a concern for security.

Comment: Does it mean that the best way to go about this is to use the assign_attribut method and I will not hav to include the user_id in my attr_assible?

Comment: @UchennaOkafor That is what I usually do. Good luck!

Comment: Pseeing the error is not only the problem but if I add d user_id to the list of attr_accessible it will be massassigned. So the question is how to solve both issues.

Comment: Yea. Its real good luck. Thanks for all the help. It works fine now! Eventually fixed all security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are building the book, you need to do it this way:

```
current_user.new { :item => item }
```

For this to work, the `item` attribute should be mass-assignment enabled.